# SonarQube error in Azure devops when executing publish quality gate task

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, quality-gate

When I run the sonar analysis on my code there is no problem, even the results are published in the Sonar tool but when executing the publish quality gate task the pipeline fails and shows the following error:

> ##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 400
>
> ##[error][SQ] Could not fetch task for ID 'AXw8YqgBUKkK2z5OofBY'

Looking over the error I came across the following solution where it tells me that I should update the sonar version: [SonarQube Publish Quality Gate Result error 400: API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68683937/sonarqube-publish-quality-gate-result-error-400-api-get-api-ce-task-failed)

But it seems very strange to me because **until yesterday it worked without problems** I would like to know if there is another possible solution or another diagnosis about this.

I am using azure devops and the version of Sonarqube that I currently have is: ***Version 6.7.5 (build 38563)***